How to Ensure Vue js Host App Can Access All Chunks of a Remote Module in Webpack Module Federation?
I am trying to load a remote application via a host app using Module Federation with vite. These are both vue applications and I have a class called plugin.ts that sets up the routes when loaded, but I encounter an error in the devtools console: "Plugin failed to load: TypeError: f.init is not a function"
This error occurs because when the host attempts to load the remote app, it cannot download the other chunks that contain the plugin code. When I load the application as a standalone all of the files load fine but when I attempt to load it in the host application it doesn't download the other host files.
Configuration:
Here is my configuration for the module federation remote application:
.use(webpack.container.ModuleFederationPlugin, [
  {
    name: 'client',
    filename: 'js/remoteEntry.js',
    exposes: {
      './Plugin': '@/plugin.ts',
    },
    remotes: {
      EcoSecurity: dynamicImport(process.env.VUE_APP_ECO_SECURITY_PATH, 'EcoSecurity', ['./Login', './Store']),
    },
    shared: [
      {
        vue: {
          eager: true,
          singleton: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
]);

Configuration:
Here is my configuration for the module federation host application:
plugins: [
      vue({
        template: {
          compilerOptions: {
            isCustomElement: tag => tag.includes('uds-'),
          },
        },
      }),
      federation({
        name: 'shell',
        exposes: {
          './Router': '@/router/index.ts',
        },
        remotes: {
          header: 'http://localhost:4174/assets/remoteEntry.js',
          navigation: 'http://localhost:4175/assets/remoteEntry.js',
          stores: 'http://localhost:4176/assets/remoteEntry.js',
          bwmclient: 'http://localhost:5002/js/remoteEntry.js',
        },
        shared: ['vue', 'pinia'],
      }),

Question:
How can I ensure that the host app can access all the JavaScript chunks that exist in the same dist folder as the remote application? Is there a specific configuration or setup required to make sure the host app can download and use these chunks?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Additional Context:
I have done this and it works with another remote application that uses the Vite bundler. Both the host and this other app use Vite, and it works fine. The difference is that the app which is not working is using Webpack instead of Vite and I am not sure if this might have anything to do with why it is not able to download the chunks.
